# Building a Target by Including a Non-Existing File

Tags: makefile, include, gnu, target

I have a simple Makefile that I am trying to understand and find documentation for why it works, so I'm hoping someone here can help me with both aspects.

Here is my Makefile:

```
TEMP_DIR = ~/Desktop/temp

default:
    $(info "reached default")

$(TEMP_DIR)/myfile.txt:
    $(info "running temp_dir target")

-include $(addprefix $(TEMP_DIR)/, myfile.txt)
```

Now I understand that when you call make without passing a target, it will read the entire Makefile and then process the first target. In this case it would be the target `default`.

When make reads the last line, it will check to see if the file `myfile.txt` is there and include it. If it's not, then it should not throw any error because I am using the `-include` directive. As stated from the GNU make manual:

> If you want make to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist or
>   cannot be remade, with no error message, use the -include directive
>   instead of include

However, by including this non-existent file, it causes the second target to be executed. So I get the following output when I run make:

```
"running temp_dir target"
"reached default"
make: `default' is up to date.
```

My question is, why is it executing that target? My second question is, is there documentation about building targets by including non-existent files? This doesn't seem like a traditional way of rebuilding a target to me.

Also as some further study, if I comment out the include line, I get the following output:

```
"reached default"
make: `default' is up to date.
```

That way I can confirm that including the non-existent file is actually causing the second target to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the answer.

The GNU Makefile manual uses this method for rebuilding makefiles when including them. The manual states:

> To this end, after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each
>   as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule
>   which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in
>   another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it (see Using Implicit
>   Rules), it will be updated if necessary.

In other words, every file that is included is considered a goal target. And that's why, when I include the file `myfile.txt`, it runs the recipe for the target that matches that file.

Here's the link to where I found the answer:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles